# How to prevent state change when hovering on an overlaid text on an image

Tags: css

So, I have an image that changes its brightness when you hover on it and reverts to its original brightness when you hover out of it. It also has a caption on top of it in the center. The problem is when I hover on the caption, it's recognized as hovering out of the image.

CSS:

```
.collection-img {
    background-image: url("sample.png");
    filter: brightness(70%);
}

.collection-img:hover {
    filter: brightness(100%);
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

This is how I use the elements in Pug-style:

```
div
    span.bg-img.collection-img
    span.caption {{ collection.caption }}
```

Comment: You can try putting the `span.caption` _inside_ the `img` element instead of as a sibling

Comment: add the code link then we know exactly what was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is when I hover on the caption, it's recognized as hovering out of the image.

Then add the `:hover` styles to the whole parent element (`div`), not just the image (`.collection-img`):

```
div:hover .collection-img { 
    filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this solution before, but it also changes the brightness of the caption text which I don't want to happen.

Comment: @Bargain23 see the updated answer. Add the `hover` event to the parent, but only change those `.collection-img` styles.